# Reqiurejs and Backbone - Collection fetch

Tags: backbone.js, collections, requirejs, fetch

When I manually define my collection content, everything works. But after I try to fetch data from server(I get valid response), my View is not showing. Collection View (ul) is showing, but single views (li) are not ? Is there something I need to watch when fetching data to collection ?

**UPDATE**

***main.js***

```
    require.config({

   paths: {

       "jquery":"vendor/jquery/jquery",
       "underscore":"vendor/underscore-amd/underscore",
       "backbone":"vendor/backbone-amd/backbone",
       "text":"../vendor/requirejs/text",
       "mustache": "../vendor/mustache/mustache"

   },

    shim: {

        underscore: {
          exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
          deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
          exports: 'Backbone'
        } 
  }


});

require([

  'app',
], function(App){
  // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
  App.initialize();
});
```

***app.js***

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/ObjaveCollection',
  'views/ObjaveView'

], function($, _, Backbone,ObjaveCollection,ObjaveView){

  var initialize = function(){

      var objave = new ObjaveCollection(); 
      objave.fetch();

      var objaveView = new ObjaveView({ collection: objave});
      $(document.body).append(objaveView.render().el);

    }

  return {

      initialize : initialize

  };
});
```

***ObjavaModel.js***

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){

    var ObjavaModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

        defaults:{

            naslov: 'My service',
            cijena: 100,

        }

    });


  return ObjavaModel;

});
```

***ObjaveCollection.js***

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/ObjavaModel'
], function($, _,Backbone,ObjavaModel){

        var ObjaveCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: ObjavaModel

    });

  return ObjaveCollection;

});
```

***ObjavaView.js***

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/objavaTemplate.html',
  'mustache',

], function($, _, Backbone,objavaTemplate,Mustache){

    var ObjavaView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: "li",

       initialize: function () {

            this.template = objavaTemplate;

        },

        render: function() {

        rendered = Mustache.to_html(this.template, this.model.toJSON());
       $(this.el).html(rendered);


         return this;
        }

    });

  return ObjavaView;

});
```

***ObjaveView.js***

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/ObjavaView'

], function($, _, Backbone,ObjavaView){

     var ObjaveView = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: 'ul',

        render: function() {
       this.collection.each(function(item) {
        console.log(item);
       var objavaView = new ObjavaView({ model: item });
       console.log(this.$el);
        this.$el.append(objavaView.render().el);
    }, this);

   return this;

  }

});

  return ObjaveView;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you rerendering your view after the data has been fetched? For example, in your view (ObjaveView.js) add:

```
initialize: function () {
  this.listenTo(this.collection, "sync", this.render);
}
```

Comment: No, I am trying to see my mistake. I have updated the question and added my code. Thank you for Your reply.

Comment: Try adding the above snippet to ObjaveView.js, that should work

Comment: in app.js, if you replace objave.fetch(); with objave.reset([{test: 1}, {test: 2}]); (or some more realistic data) it works?

Comment: Yes, i have tried with this , var objave = new ObjaveCollection([
      {
         naslov: 'Prvi item',
         cijena: 100
      },
      {
         naslov: 'Drugi item',
         cijena: 50,

      }
     
      ]);

Comment: What do you get logged to console if you replace objave.fetch() in app.js with `objave.on('reset', function () {console.log('fetched!', objave.length, 'items');}).fetch();`

Comment: Nothing is loged , except two successful XMLHttpRequests. XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/Requirejs/vjezba3/js/templates/objavaTemplate.html". text.js:303
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/Requirejs/RequirejsServer1/dobavi_objave.php". jquery.js:8556

Comment: seems like the data is not being sent correctly? are you responding to the ajax request with Content-Type application/json and JSON data? Do you the array of JSON data in your network panel under the Response tab in the relevant xhr request?

Comment: Thaky you very much for your time. Here is request response:

[{"id":"1","naziv":"Test","sadrzaj":"test"}]

Comment: Looks all right.. Can you try this line instead and see if any event gets triggered on the collection: `objave.on('all', function () {console.log(arguments);}).fetch();`

Comment: This is loged. XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/Requirejs/vjezba3/js/templates/objavaTemplate.html". text.js:303
["request", child, Object, Object]
 app.js:14
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost/Requirejs/RequirejsServer1/dobavi_objave.php". jquery.js:8556
["add", child, child, Object]
 app.js:14
["sort", child, Object]
 app.js:14
["sync", child, Array[1], Object]

Comment: Interesting! The I forgot the behaviour changed slightly in Backbone 1.1.0. So, in your ObjaveView.js instead of what I suggested, add the this.collection.on("sync", this.render, this); (I'm updating the answer)

Comment: YOU ARE ABSOLUTE PROFESIONAL AND YOU SHOUD BE PROUD OF YOUR SKILLS.

Comment: I updated the answer once more - use listenTo whenever you can - this way when you remove your view using view.remove(); the event listeners are gonna be removed and will help you avoid memory leaks.